# NServiceBus RavenDb - view ServiceControl database outside localhost

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I've ServiceControl, ServicePulse & RavelDb all installed in a production server. Unfortunately, I can't run any browser in this server for security reasons. I would like to view the database used by ServiceControl. When I connect to the RavenDb server remotely in my desktop browser (http://server:8080), I could see all the end points databases but I don't see the database created for ServiceControl.

I applied the settings to expose RavenDb as :

The ServiceControl documentation says the db is visible at http://localhost:33333/storage which is not an option for me (no browser is allowed in this server)

I have customized the ServiceControl host name, so http://server:33333/api is reachable but http://server:33333/storage returns 404.

Any thoughts/solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the documentation here](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/use-ravendb-studio), my guess is that you are missing the configuration bit.